# Quarkus: Unable to open web socket connection when i have custom http root path

Tags: websocket, quarkus

I am unable to open a web socket connection on Quarkus when I have set the property `quarkus.http.root-path` in `application.properties`. But the socket connection is ok when I disable the property `quarkus.http.root-path`.

Is there any workaround to open the socket connection when I have set the property value to `quarkus.http.root-path`?

Comment: Go through the Quarkus docs :- https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference

Comment: I have the same issue. Any solutions?